# SQLView not working

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle-apex

How come this is not working?

I am trying to create a view that views job vacancies that are between 2 dates.

1 being greater or equal to todays and the closing date being less than or equal to todays date.

**Any ideas?**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW  "VIEW_JOB_VACANCIES" ("JOB_ID", "JOB_TITLE", "JOB_DESCRIPTION", "JOB_EMAIL_ADDRESS", "JOB_CONTACT_NUMBER", "JOB_SALARY", "APPLICATION_METHOD", "START_DATE", "CLOSING_DATE", "SITE_ID") AS 
  SELECT job_id, job_title, job_description, job_email_address, job_contact_number, job_salary, application_method, start_date, closing_date, site_id 
FROM jobs
WHERE start_date >= sysdate
AND closing_date <= sysdate
```

Comment: define "not working", what's the error?

Comment: @kostyan Its responding with no data found. When there is clearly data to view.

Comment: check conditions, does select on its own return anything?

Comment: can you put some sample data that you think should be there? Your where clause looks a little suspicious.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't start_date supposed to be less than closing_date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the logic in your WHERE clause is backwards.  The way you have it will only return records where the start date is after the closing date:

(`start_date >= sysdate AND sysdate >= closing_date` implies that `start_date >= closing_date`)

Try this:

```
WHERE start_date <= sysdate
AND closing_date >= sysdate
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Use between

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW  "VIEW_JOB_VACANCIES" ("JOB_ID", "JOB_TITLE",     "JOB_DESCRIPTION", "JOB_EMAIL_ADDRESS", "JOB_CONTACT_NUMBER", "JOB_SALARY", "APPLICATION_METHOD", "START_DATE", "CLOSING_DATE", "SITE_ID") AS 
  SELECT job_id, job_title, job_description, job_email_address, job_contact_number,     job_salary, application_method, start_date, closing_date, site_id 
FROM jobs
WHERE sysdate between start_date AND closing_date
```